# mock store getters inside Global Guard does not work

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils, vue-testing-library

I created a global guard that uses getters from store.

I am trying to mock some getters from store for testing purpose. The problem is that mocking

does not work.

```js
// router/index.ts
export function beforeEach(to: any, from: any, next: any) {
  const isLoggedIn = store.getters.isLoggedIn();
  const isGuest = to.matched.some((record: any) => (record.meta.guest));
  if (isLoggedIn) { // isLoggedIn is always false
    if (isGuest) {
      next('/');
    }
  } 
  }
}
```

```js
//router/index.spec.ts
describe('shoud test routing functionality', () => {
it('should redirect to / when isLoggedIn is true and IsGuest is true', () => {
    // given
    jest.mock('@/store', () => ({
      getters: {
        isLoggedIn: jest.fn().mockImplementation(
          () => true, // <----------- this value is always false
        ),
      },
    }));

     // even this one does not work
     //  jest.spyOn(getters, 'isLoggedIn').mockImplementation(() => 
     //  ()=> true);

    const to = {
      matched: [{ meta: { guest: true } }],
    };
    const next = jest.fn();

    // when
    beforeEach(to, undefined, next);

    // then
    expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/');
  });
})
```

I inspired from this [example](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vue-router.html#global-guards).

Comment: jest.mock inside a test can't affect top-level imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @EstusFlask comment, I solved the problem.

The keyword is that **jest.mock inside a test can't affect top-level imports**.

```
jest.mock('@/store', () => ({
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: jest.fn(),
  // other methods should be declared here, otherwise an exception is thrown
    isSuperAdmin: jest.fn(),
    isAdmin: jest.fn(),
    isReadUser: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

describe('should test routing functionality', () => {
   it('should redirect to / when isLoggedIn is true and IsGuest is true', () => {
    // given
    store.getters.isLoggedIn.mockImplementation(() => () => false);
    const to = {
      matched: [{ meta: { guest: true } }],
    };
    const next = jest.fn();

    // when
    beforeEach(to, undefined, next);

    // then
    expect(next).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/');
  });
})
```